# Simple mp3 player works fine on emulator but doesn't work on actual device

Tags: android

So I followed this tutorial on how to create a simple music player and works just fine on genymotion, now I want to run it on my phone but it crashes from the start, here is my code

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY=500;
private static final int STEP_VALUE=4000;

private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter=null;
private TextView selectedfile=null;
private SeekBar seekbar=null;
private MediaPlayer player=null;
private ImageButton PlayButton=null;
private ImageButton PrevButton=null;
private ImageButton NextButton=null;

private boolean isStarted=true;
private String currentFile="";
private boolean isMovingSeekBar=false;

private final Handler handler=new Handler();

private final Runnable updatepostionRunnable=new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updatePostion();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    selectedfile=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
    seekbar=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    PlayButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.play);
    PrevButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.prev);
    NextButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);

    player=new MediaPlayer();

    player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
    player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);

    Cursor cursor= 

getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null,null
,null,null);
    if (null !=cursor){
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter= new MediaCursorAdapter(this, 
R.layout.listitem,cursor);

        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);

        PlayButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        NextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        PrevButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView list,View view,int position,long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(list,view,position,id);

    currentFile=(String)view.getTag();

    startplay(currentFile);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    handler.removeCallbacks(updatepostionRunnable);
    player.stop();
    player.reset();
    player.release();

    player=null;
}

private void startplay(String file){
    Log.i("Selected ", file);
    selectedfile.setText(file);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);

    player.stop();
    player.reset();

    try{
        player.setDataSource(file);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());

    PlayButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
    updatePostion();
    isStarted=true;
}

private void stopplay(){
    player.stop();
    player.reset();
    PlayButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatepostionRunnable);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);

    isStarted=false;
}

private void updatePostion(){
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatepostionRunnable);

    seekbar.setProgress(player.getCurrentPosition());

    handler.postDelayed(updatepostionRunnable,UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
}

  private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c){
        super(context,layout,c,
                new String[]{MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
  MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                new int[]{R.id.displayname,R.id.title,R.id.duration});
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context,Cursor cursor){
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        name.setText(cursor.getString(

cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        long durationInMs=Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(

cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION)));

        double durationInMin = ((double) durationInMs /1000.0 ) / 60.0;
        durationInMin = new 

 BigDecimal(Double.toString(durationInMin)).setScale(
 2,BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).doubleValue();
        duration.setText("" + durationInMin);




view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,parent,false);
        bindView(v,context,cursor);
        return v;
    }
}
private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick=new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.play:{
                if(player.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updatepostionRunnable);
                    player.pause();

PlayButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                }else{
                    if (isStarted){
                        player.start();

PlayButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

                        updatePostion();
                    }else{
                        startplay(currentFile);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.next:{
                int seekto=player.getCurrentPosition()+STEP_VALUE;

                if(seekto>player.getDuration()){
                    seekto=player.getDuration();
                }

                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.prev:{
                int seekto=player.getCurrentPosition()- STEP_VALUE;

                if (seekto<0){
                    seekto=0;
                }
                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion= new 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
  @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
      stopplay();
  }
};

private  MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError=new 
MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp,int what, int extra){
    return false;
    }
};

private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new 
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
fromUser) {
        if (isMovingSeekBar){
            player.seekTo(progress);
            Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener","onProgressChanged");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMovingSeekBar=true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMovingSeekBar=false;
    }

};



}
```

here's the monitor error thing

```
    04-16 20:25:40.009 2516-2516/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

04-16 20:25:40.039 2516-2516/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9515_4.4.2_0040


04-16 20:25:40.039 2516-2516/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-16 20:25:40.039 2516-2516/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
04-16 20:25:40.039 2516-2516/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer [ userId:0 | appId:10200 ]
04-16 20:25:40.039 2516-2516/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-16 20:25:40.139 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer, real application class is null.
04-16 20:25:40.149 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath
04-16 20:25:40.169 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer W/ApplicationPackageManager: getCSCPackageItemText()
04-16 20:25:40.169 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer I/PersonaManager: getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-16 20:25:40.219 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-16 20:25:40.239 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/ProgressBar: setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 36
04-16 20:25:40.249 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsSeekBar: AbsSeekBar Constructor: misSeebarAnimationAvailable = true
04-16 20:25:40.259 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer V/MediaPlayer-JNI: native_setup
04-16 20:25:40.259 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer V/MediaPlayer: constructor
04-16 20:25:40.259 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer V/MediaPlayer: setListener
04-16 20:25:40.319 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-16 20:25:40.319 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-16 20:25:40.339 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-16 20:25:40.339 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-16 20:25:40.339 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AbsListView: unregisterIRListener() is called 
04-16 20:25:40.359 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-16 20:25:40.359 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x420c3da0)
04-16 20:25:40.370 2516-2516/com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer, PID: 2516
                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "null"
                                                                                        at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:341)
                                                                                        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
                                                                                        at com.bignerdranch.android.musicplayer.MainActivity$MediaCursorAdapter.bindView(MainActivity.java:164)
                                                                                        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
                                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2694)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
                                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5352)
                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2533)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1352)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1551)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6473)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)

    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

help please and thank you

Comment: Did you read the stack trace? (You need to post that as text, btw, not as a screenshot.) You're getting a `NumberFormatException` because you're calling `Long.parseLong()` on null in your `Adapter`'s `bindView()` method.

Comment: uploaded the stack trace, yes I've read it, I just know that Long.parseLong() is null for some reason, any idea why?

Comment: Yeah, apparently the `DURATION` column isn't returning what you expect. Or, if you do expect that it sometimes might not have a value, you're not accounting for it. You can use `cursor.getLong()` instead of `getString()`, and drop the `Long.parseLong()` call altogether, if you're OK with 0 as a duration for those entries that don't have a value.

Comment: Dude you're a life savor, THANK you so much, it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the emulator and device you have are using two different XML layout files in two different resource buckets.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You are getting a null pointer in the bind method of the adapter, because it does a `findViewById` and the view cannot be found in the supplied layout file. This then returns `null` and if you try and call a method on `null` you get your crash.

Solution: find the layout file you use (`listitem.xml`), and either update it in that res bucket to have the views you expect, or delete it so it falls back to a correct xml file (the one the emulator is using).

Comment: what do you mean by"update it" ? make sure of the components names?

Comment: "update it" = open the xml layout file and ensure it has all the views and `android:id`'s you want to use